# ionic 3 show image of imagepicker or capture by camera in html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to show image of capture picture or slected picture in .html . This is how im showing but in this its showing error of photo not defined. i try with photo: any; photo:string ; but not solved .

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-12 text-center>
                  <ion-img (click)="setImage()" style="width:120px;height:120px"  [src]="deal?.photo || 'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/21845/screenshots/3938419/placeholder.png'" height="120px"></ion-img>    
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

.ts

```
takePicture() {
this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
  this.helper.load();

  let id=Date.now();
  const image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`;
  const pictures = this.storage.ref('deal/'+id);
  pictures.putString(image, 'data_url').then((r: UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
      r.ref.getDownloadURL().then(res=>{
       this.deal=res;  // here is the image i want to show 
       this.helper.dismiss();
      })

  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    this.helper.toast(err);
    this.helper.dismiss();
  });

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);

});
}
```

im using some one code. previously its using this.deal.photo = res . Which is also working to upload on firebase but showing error photo not defined. when i removed photo its workingbut not showing the image in .html.

I need to know how can i show deal in home.html previously im showing like [src]="deal?.photo" im doing like [src]="deal" so its showing some token error

Comment: suggest you to check that res contains photo key and value.

Answer (score 0):

The image URL may have a "file" prefix appended to it, which can be removed by the call:

`this.deal=normalizeURL(res);`

or maybe (I can't quite tell from your code):

`this.deal.photo=normalizeURL(res);`

You can read about normalizeURL [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/3.2.0/api/util/normalizeURL/).

Comment: No, it's part of Ionic. Did you spell it right "normalizeURL"?